# Get all records having count from one table is greater than sum of other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables 1) **CustomerOrders**, 2) **StockItems** and 3) **OrderContentsLine**. `StockItems` have `customerorderid` (one to many relationship with `CustomerOrders`) and `OrderContentsLine` contains order items with item quantity (obviously one to many relationship with `CustomerOrders`).

Now I want to get All orders which have sum of quantity from `OrderContentsLine` table greater than count of `StockItems`

myquery looks like this

```
select co.OrderNumber,si.SalesOrderID, sum(ocl.Quantity) Ordered, count(si.SalesOrderID) Allocated from CustomerOrders co
inner join StockItems si on co.OrderID = si.SalesOrderID
inner join OrderContentsLine ocl on ocl.OrderID=co.OrderID
where co.CompanyId=531
group by si.SalesOrderID,co.OrderNumber
having count(si.SalesOrderID)>sum(ocl.Quantity)
```

but this query shows no results, and I am damn sure that many orders have greater order conterntline items than sum of quantity from StockItems table.

Can you please review my query and suggest the better way to get these orders!

My required output is

[image]

> NOTE: this output is not generated by query !

I have just created a query that gives me the required output

```
select * from(
select co.OrderNumber, co.OrderID, co.OrderStatus,
(select sum(tbl.Quantity) from OrderContentsLine tbl where tbl.OrderID=co.OrderID) Ordered, 
(select count(*) from StockItems tbl2 where tbl2.SalesOrderID=co.OrderID ) Allocated 
from CustomerOrders co
)temp where temp.Allocated> temp.Ordered
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Remove the HAVING clause for a while and see if that result makes sense.

Comment: so you think my query is correct according to requirements ?

Comment: That is not what @jarlh is saying, we cannot know if your query is correct without more information. You should provide us with sample data and expected outcome, and provide them in text format not as image. Only then we will be able to check your query if it is correct or not

Comment: I have edited the question with required output

Comment: You query does not contain any condition to check if an order exceed number of item in stock. And your screenshot also does not reflect this - all orders < StockItems as i can see. It would be easier for us if you can provide some sample data in each tables too, or even DDL if possible

Comment: Required output is meaninless without input data, please provide sample data, and DO NOT add it as image ! Add it as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the multiple one-to-many joins. You are counting and summing duplicates. For example, if you have 1 order with 2 stock items, and 3 order lines, your join of the three tables will have 6 rows. You have no relationship between StockItem and OrderContentsLine, so you get a cartesian product.

You probably want something like

```
WITH ord AS 
(
    SELECT co.CompanyId, co.OrderID, co.OrderNumber, SUM(ocl.Quantity) AS Ordered
    FROM CustomerOrders co
    INNER JOIN OrderContentsLine ocl ON ocl.OrderID = co.OrderID
    GROUP BY co.CompanyId, co.OrderNumber
), al AS
(
    SELECT co.CompanyId, co.OrderID, co.OrderNumber, COUNT(si.SalesOrderID) AS Allocated
    FROM CustomerOrders co
    INNER JOIN StockItems si ON co.OrderID = si.SalesOrderID
    GROUP BY co.CompanyId, co.OrderNumber
)
SELECT ord.CompanyId, ord.OrderNumber, ord.Ordered, al.Allocated
FROM ord 
INNER JOIN al ON ord.OrderID = al.OrderID
WHERE companyId = 531
AND al.Allocated > ord.Ordered
```

Obviously hard to test with no data

Comment: Just noticed you added your own solution. subqueries instead of ctes is a similar way of tacking the same issue